# Why Last key missing from dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

Code is below

```
from decimal import Decimal
sample = [
    ("Book", Decimal("10.000"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pen", Decimal("66.66666"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pencil", Decimal("100.0000"), Decimal("0E-20"), '133.33'),
]


datalst=[]    

for i in sample:
    data = {} 
    try:
        if i[0] is not None:
            data['prod'] = i[0]
        else:
             data['prod'] = 0
        if i[1] is not None:
            data['test1'] = round(i[1])
        else:
             data['test1'] = 0
        if i[2] is not None:
            data['test2'] = round(i[2])
        else:
             data['test2'] = 0
        if i[3] is not None:
            data['test3'] = round(i[3])
        else:
             data['test3'] = 0
    except:
        
        pass   
    datalst.append(data)  

print(datalst)
```

Current out

```
[{'prod': 'Book', 'test1': 10, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pen', 'test1': 67, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pencil', 'test1': 100, 'test2': 0}]
```

Expected Out

```
[{'prod': 'Book', 'test1': 10, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pen', 'test1': 67, 'test2': 0, 'test3': 0}, {'prod': 'Pencil', 'test1': 100, 'test2': 0, 'test3':133}]
```

From out last key is missing from the dictionary  `test3':133`

Comment: You're applying a round function on a string variable. It most likely returns a TypeError which is caught by your non-specific `except: pass` statement

Comment: I recommend practicing _minimizing_ code. It all boils down to `round('133.33')`, at which point the problem and fix is probably pretty obvious. See also [Pokemon exception handling](https://wiki.c2.com/?PokemonExceptionHandling) which this code proves is poor practice because it stifles all errors and keeps the program running under circumstances you may not have anticipated. If there is a failure, no useful error message is emitted as is the case here.

Comment: First convert from string to float then apply round ``round(float(i[3]), 2)``

Comment: Only ignore *specific* exceptions that you expect. It's not clear what exception you think is safe to ignore here.

Comment: I actually shocked when Python didn't raise exception for `round("133.33")` then I saw `except: pass` ... This is really a bad habit that you should avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `try: ... except: pass` and defined '133.33' which is a string that goes straight to the except: pass when you put it through `round()` function.  Convert string to a decimal first and all good

```
from decimal import Decimal
sample = [
    ("Book", Decimal("10.000"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pen", Decimal("66.66666"), Decimal("0E-20"), None),
    ("Pencil", Decimal("100.0000"), Decimal("0E-20"), '133.33'),
]

datalst = [{"prod":i[0], "test1":round(i[1]), "test2":round(i[2]), 
            "test3":round(Decimal(i[3])) if i[3] is not None else 0} for i in sample]

print(datalst)
```